# HTML5 form misinterprets a number field for a credit card number, how to overrule?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've got a simple number field (11 digits). When I test it in Chrome, it suggests to put a credit card number in the field, which is not the aim of the input. Is there a way to overrule this behavior, to just accept a regular 11 digit number?

The rendered input looks like this:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Number (11 cijfers)" pattern=".{3,}" type="text" name="user[number]" id="user_number">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to the input field https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: I tried that, but it still shows the pop-up. I'm testing this site on localhost, could that have impact?